# Why do we say "This jacket is the wrong size"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, phrase-usage

A jacket is a thing and a size is a measurement and a jacket can not be a measurement.

Why do we say "**This jacket is the wrong size**" which sounds like "**This jacket is a measurement**"?

Comment: The "size" here means "the size of garment".  It's not just any measurement.

Comment: It's entirely arbitrary. We can say, "*This jacket has a size*", but not, "*This jacket **is** a size*."

Comment: @gotube - I can imagine discomfort if I bought a hat a size smaller than the right one, and ridicule if it was a size bigger.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Is this related to the question?

Comment: @gotube - it hopes to address your comment about saying that an item of clothing 'is a size'. My hat is a size bigger than it should be. My hat size is seven. This hat is a seven and one-eighth.

Comment: It's correct to say, "*My hat is a size bigger than it should be*", but not "*My hat is a size*". Instead, we say, "*My hat **has** a size*", even though we cannot say, "*My hat **has** a size bigger than it should be*." That's what I mean by it's arbitrary. There's obviously no guiding reason why English chose "is" over "has" in that sentence, given simpler sentences do use "has" and no "is".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is how the word "size", and similar words like "age" or "price", works

So you can say that it's the wrong, or right size.  Or you can ask "What size is it?"

And you can say "What age is it?" or "It's the right price" and so on.  I don't know if this class of words has a name, but you should be able to think of some more that can be used the same way.